# Conditional page adding in RDLC report

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rdlc

I work on an MVC application that generates reports from rdlc files. Particularly, i have a WS that generates a PDF document with one or more DataSources with a single page rdlc file.

Now my problem is : the customer wants to add a page between each page, only if a certain condition is satisfied. I can modify my rdlc file to add this document, but i can't get it to show only certain times...

I've tried playing with visibility, page breaks but it doesn't work. I've even thought about generating each page independently and merging it in one PDF file.

What would be a clean way to do it ?

Comment: Please add some code for reference

Comment: Do you mean blank page when you say "page between each page"?

Answer (score 0):

If you have all your page-breaking set correctly, which you claim you did, you could wrap the extra page inside a `Rectangle` where you define an expression for the hidden property.
When this rectangle becomes hidden the entire page shouldn't be rendered.

If you need help with defining the expression you'll have to share a lot more information but this shouldn't really be a problem to achieve by yourself.